# HSV color to RGB color Algorithm - Linearly Interpolated colors

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, rgb, hsv

Develop an algorithm for converting an HSV colour value into RGB colour and explain how and why it works correctly. Then consider the two HSV colours h1 = (156, 0.625, 0.8) and h2 = (300, 0.6, 0.5) and convert them into RGB (giving r1 and r2), CMY (c1, c2), and CMYK (k1, k2). Finally, compute the linearly interpolated colors h3 = 0.3h1 + 0.7h2 and r3 = 0.3r1 + 0.7r2 and compare them after having converted r3 into HSV.

I have found the formula from the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV) but I don't know what I have to do in order to get the correct result. I am confused with the CMY and CMYK and the linearly interpolated colors I have to compute too. So any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the formulas that were given in class for these conversions?  At least then someone can help you with the code to implement the formulas.

Comment: I have only the formula for the reverse conversion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert RGB color to CMYK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426432/convert-rgb-color-to-cmyk)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4106363/21727

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change RGB color to HSV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359612/how-to-change-rgb-color-to-hsv)

Answer (score 1):

This site helped me a lot with the math side when doing color conversion:
http://easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH

Keep in mind that you need a profile in order to have any meaning for the CMYK and RGB values.